# Finding groups in Excel and writing it to another table

Tags: excel

I need some help with Excel table.
I have some data in groups e.g

```
id   name
192  1 group
1    member group 1
2    member group 1
202  2 group 
5    member group 2
6    member group 2
```

What I am trying to do is when I type e.g number `192` I want to get whole group. So result would be

```
192  1 group
    1    member group 1
    2    member group 1
```

I was trying with funciton VLOOKUP but it displays me only the group name and id.
Is there some way so when I type 192 I get whole group.

Thank you so much for reading and I appreciate any kind of help

NOTE: GROUP ALWAYS HAS THREE DIGIT AND MEMBERS ALWAYS HAVE ONE DIGIT

Comment: What's the difference between a group and a member? i.e. how can you tell which is which? I believe using a helper column and filter would be more straightforward. Using formulae will make it much more complex, slower and unless you have a maximum number of members in a group, you'll have to make sure you have enough formulae to cater for each member (if there are not enough, you'll have to drag the formula across more rows for instance).

Comment: There is no connection between them. But I can add more columns if you have any idea how it would help. Simply I want when I search group 192 for the result to have also groups member. Thank you for any help

Comment: Is the group name actually `1 group` then? And are the group IDs always 3 digits long while the members have IDs less than 3 digits long?  Otherwise how would someone be sure that `202  2 group` is not just another member of `192  1 group`? with some fancy ID and name?

Comment: Group always has three digits and members always one digit

Answer (score 0):

I'd use at most 2 helper columns (one for the group ID and one for the group name) and use those formulae in:

C2:

```
=IF(A2>=100,A2,C1)
```

D2:

```
=IF(A2>=100,B2,D1)
```

Then drag the formula down the table.

[image]

If you want to see the group members in group ID 192, then you simply need to filter on Group ID 192 and read the members:

[image]

Comment: But what if I am working in another table or in another document and I want to use group 3 and 4. So when I type 192 I want to get result from this table group and member. Something similar to VLOOKUP but I dont know how to perfrom this with VLOOKUP beacuase vlookup is returning only group not members.

Comment: @HardRock It would probably be better to merge all the tables into one.

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to have more than one source of data, and when there is no way around it, there is usually a software that does the merging behind the scenes.

Comment: I agree, but I really need this way. So I have this sheet with thousands of groups and I am making new sheet every day. Every day I need different groups e.g today group 202,203,304,404,etc. It would be very useful to display member of groups automatically and to search them manually. If you have any idea how to do this it would reallay helped me. Thank you so much

Comment: Sorry, I think the solution you are looking for might be ine VBA realm (which I avoid for the life of me). It should be possible to do something like 'select source range' then you select it and it asks you for the group number, and after that create a new sheet or something with the members.